# IOS MVC pattern and data controller for manipulating NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, nsmutablearray

I have: 
 a class called Care
 an NSMutableArray that is called masterCareList
 masterView, detailView  
 careDataController for adding Cares to List and count number of objects. 
  
I want to count my objects in MasterView and I want to add an object in detailView. In both cases using the careDataController (not rewind segue or passing data between views) and to the same masterCareList.

How do I use the same dataController and therefore the same NSMutable array in the best (MVC) way?

Comment: To solve it I now pass my dataController from masterView to detailView through the prepareForSeque method. This doesnt however feel correct because I dont want to send the dataController around. I 'm wondering if I should use delegates? Do I then turn my dataController into a protocol?

Comment: was my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your careDataController on initial setup of your app and access the careDataController through a property of MasterView.  This would enable you to encapsulate counting and other operations on your data separate from your view controller.

a very high level example somewhere where you create MasterView...AppDelegate maybe...

```
//Appdelegate.m file
MasterView *mv = [[MasterView alloc] init];
DataController *careDataController = [[DataController alloc] init];
mc.model = careDataController;  //model is a property within MasterView that you create

[self presentViewController:mv animated:YES completion:nil];
```

now you could essentially in MasterView present the DetailView after creating it and setting its model property you create to MasterViews model property you set above.

```
//some procedure in MasterView.m
DetailView *dv = [[DetailView alloc] init];
dv.model = self.model; //self.model you set above

[self presentViewController:dv animated:YES completion:nil];
```

now once in the DetailView you can add care objects to the original careDataController you initially created at the start of your app...

```
//somewhere in DetailView.m
Care *careObject = [[Care alloc] init];
[self.model addObject:careObject];
```

when you dismiss the DetailView after you are done adding an object your careDataController (model property) in MasterView will now have the new care object you added in the DetailView.

**EDIT:**
I see your new comment, in a way its essentially what I just wrote above which I do not feel is incorrect.  Another thing you could do is instead of passing it like above, have MasterView be a delegate for DetailView.  When you add a Care object save that object state in DetailView and pass it back using a the protocol you defined in DetailView.  You might have a method in the protocol like below that MasterView implements...

```
-(void)detailView:(DetailView *)dv didInsert:(Care*)careObject
{
    [self.model addObject:careObject];
}
```

Comment: @djcj was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: I think so, I have now implemented all the functionality I want but not according to the MVC structure I want. So I will now try to move as much logic as possible to the dataController and also have a closer look at your answer!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This article doesnt really help but its interesting: http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/ 

Anyway, I am now trying to set the datamodell in appDelegate since I dont get the managedObjectContext "with me" otherwise. So I have: CareDataController *dataController;
dataController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.dataController = dataController;

The problem is that the dataController is not passed to the detailView.

Comment: I would check out https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord if you are using core data.  You are going to fall in love with core data all over again using it.  I think this will help you with your above situation.